# Can quick charge be enabled with custom rom?

Tags: custom-roms

Suppose I have a device (eg Redmi 4) which inherently has quick charge 3.0 support but the developer has disabled the feature to save the cost, then can I by installing the custom rom enable it?

Comment: A custom kernel can, but when the manufacturer themselves don't offer it, devs often can't make the most out of it. Redmi Note 3 got aftermarket QC support but the voltage is still locked at 5V, just with a larger current.